# Why my text goes out of content editable div?

Tags: html, css, fonts, contenteditable, font-feature-settings

My text goes out of content editable div.

`.mydiv { font-family: "Black Hairline Italic"; font-feature-settings: "ss16"; }`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBcp0.png)

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie here, so I didn't know the rule. I've updated the question and provided link. Could you please help?

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878) - no. A proper [mre] belongs directly inside your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.